# Skyrim mods for the PS3?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3

Is it possible to get mods for Skyrim on a PS3 console? I haven't tried any and didn't know they even existed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can.  I have only done it on PS4 and on a save I didn't plan on keeping as it turns off trophies.